# Capturing Spline Factor Attribute for Linear Interpolation on Geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

[image: FromYellowAltitudeToGreenAltitude]

I am attempting to perform linear interpolation using the spline factor, transitioning from yellow altitude to green altitude. However, when I try to capture the factor attribute, I consistently receive a value of 0 for my mix factor. Can anyone provide guidance on how to successfully achieve this interpolation? Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you exchange min + max and use a sample nearest/index node like this, you get this:

[image]

Hope that helps.